# Why didn't honey soy chicken breast brown?

Tags: chicken, marinade

I cooked chicken breasts in my countertop convection oven with a honey and soy sauce mixture and they didn't brown at all. I guess the honey and soy slid right off. Is marinading the way to make it stick? Or is it because they are skinless? I didn't marinade the chicken but spooned the mixture on top of them before baking. I used boneless chicken breasts and a lower temperature than the attached recipe (375 degrees in convection oven so like 400 degrees in a regular oven). Similar to this recipe. [Baked Asian-Style Honey Chicken](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/15005/baked-asian-style-honey-chicken/)

Comment: Did you premix the honey and soy? Could be worth bringing them to the boil, add a corn flour and water mix and when thick, turn off the heat, add the chicken, toss to coat and then transfer to oven?

Comment: @Dave yes, I premixed them but it sounds like a good idea to thicken it. Thank you!